# Hash (MD2) elements of a List<byte[]> from a large file (~5GB), using ExecutorService, invokeAll extremely slow

Tags: java, hash, parallel-processing, executorservice, large-files

I'm hashing (with MD2) a large file parallel using ExecutorService. The process is the following:
First, the "inputparser3" method decides if the input is a text or a file, if it is a file, and larger than 100MB, splits the file into chunks and store them in a List of byte[], every chunk is 10MB. Second, the "encrypt3" method hashes every chunk parallel using ExecutorService, for example using 6 threads. After, I use the futures list (with the hashes of the small chunks) to generate a master hash (root hash).

For the example, I download a test file (5GB) from this website: https://testfiledownload.com/
When I tested my code I recognized that it takes forever to finish... about 17 minutes (1000ms), without ExecutorServices and splitting it into chunks it takes only 6 minutes (400ms) on average.
I recognized that the threadPool.invokeAll(callableTasks) takes most of the time, and I believe because it has to execute 500 chunks on 6 thread.

My questions are the following:

- Is it possible to run 6 chunks at a time, I mean when the first 6 finishes start the second 6...and so on...
- Is it possible to improve somehow?
- Should I completely remove the parallelization?

My code (in main method):

```
String largefile = "C:\\Users\\Thend\\Desktop\\test_5gb\\5gb.test";

StopWatch st = new StopWatch();
st.start();
String hash = encrypt3(Objects.requireNonNull(inputparser3(largefile, "FILE")));
st.stop();
System.out.println("Hash: "+hash+" | Execution time: "+String.format("%.5f", st.getTotalTimeMillis() / 1000.0f)+"sec");
```

The methods:

```
public static List<byte[]> inputparser3(String PathOrText, String TYPE) throws IOException {
    if (TYPE.equals("TXT")) {

        List<byte[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        if(PathOrText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length > 10485760){ // 10 MB = 10485760 Bytes (in binary)

            // Add chunk by chunk
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(PathOrText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 1 MB chunk
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                temp.add(buffer);
            }
            return temp;

        } else {

            // Add whole
            temp.add(PathOrText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return temp;

        }
    } else if (TYPE.equals("FILE")) {

        List<byte[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        if(Files.size(Path.of(PathOrText)) > 104857600) { // 100 MB = 104857600 Bytes (in binary)
            // Add chunk by chunk
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PathOrText)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10485760]; //  10 MB chunk
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    temp.add(buffer);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        } else {
            // Add whole
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PathOrText)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) PathOrText.length()]; //  Add whole
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    temp.add(buffer);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Input type cannot be recognized! Use 'TXT' for text or 'FILE' for file.");
    return null;
}
public static String encrypt3(List<byte[]> list) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
    List<Callable<String>> callableTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    // If there is MORE THAN ONE element in the list
    if(list.size() > 1){

        list.forEach((n)->{
            Callable<String> callableTask = () -> {

                sb.setLength(0);
                md.reset();

                md.update(n);
                byte[] hashed_bytes = md.digest();

                for (byte hashed_byte : hashed_bytes) {sb.append(Integer.toString((hashed_byte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));}
                return sb.toString();

            };
            callableTasks.add(callableTask);
        });

        List<Future<String>> futures = threadPool.invokeAll(callableTasks);
        threadPool.shutdown();

        for (Future<String> future : futures) {
            temp.add(future.get());
        }

        // Create a master hash (root hash)
        sb.setLength(0);
        md.reset();

        md.update(String.join("", temp).getBytes());
        byte[] hashed_bytes = md.digest();
        for (byte hashed_byte : hashed_bytes) {sb.append(Integer.toString((hashed_byte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));}
        return sb.toString();

        // If there is ONLY ONE element in the list
    } else {

        sb.setLength(0);
        md.reset();

        md.update(list.get(0));
        byte[] hashed_bytes = md.digest();
        for (byte hashed_byte : hashed_bytes) {sb.append(Integer.toString((hashed_byte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));}
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code by removing ExecutorServices, and following the comments of @MarkRotteveel and @g00se.

```
public static List<byte[]> iparser4(String datatype, String input) throws IOException {
    List<byte[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    if("TXT".equals(datatype)){
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 1 MiB chunk
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            temp.add(buffer);
        }
        return temp;
    } else if("FILE".equals(datatype)){
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; //  1 MiB chunk
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                temp.add(buffer);
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static String encrypt4(List<byte[]> list) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD2");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    list.forEach((n)-> {
        ByteArrayInputStream bai = new ByteArrayInputStream(n);
        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(bai), md);
        try (bai) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];  //  1 MiB chunk
            while (true) {
                int readCount = dis.read(buffer);
                if (readCount < 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            byte[] hash = md.digest();
            for (byte hashed_byte : hash) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", hashed_byte));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        //System.out.println("Hash: "+sb.toString());
    });
    md.reset();
    byte[] masterhash = md.digest(sb.toString().getBytes());
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte hashed_byte : masterhash) {
        sb2.append(String.format("%02x", hashed_byte));
    }
    return sb2.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'd start by not repeatedly performing `PathOrText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, but your conversions also seem to be pretty convoluted and inefficient, because you load the entire thing into memory, instead of hashing it on the fly while reading it. For example, why not just read it through a `DigestInputStream`?

Comment: *First, the "inputparser3" method decides if the input is a text or a file* then you should call it something more self-documenting such as ```collectChunksAsPathOrText```  Before we go any further about the performance, you need to get the code right. For instance, how do you know how much data (as opposed to garbage) is in each chunk, in particular the last one? though it must be observed that even the first will not necessarily be complete

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It seems to me very simple, but I'm not a professional. How can I improve to simplify (not be convoluted), and also how can I make it more efficient? I'm using PathOrText because beside files I have to process large amounts of text.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right site for such a question, to be honest.

Comment: @g00se Sorry for the naming, I will change them as you suggest. I don't know if there is any part of the chunk is garbage. I assume as many chunk as necessary is created, and they not contain any garbage, maybe I misunderstood you. May I kindly ask to explain?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel do you suggest that DigestInputStream would improve the speed without parallelization?

Comment: Well the guiding principle is to get it right first so @MarkRotteveel's comment about ```DigestInputStream```  should be the first thing to address - because he's right ;) As for your question, let's say the input is text and it's 1MiB (your buffer size - note that's *not* the same as "1 MB" which is 1,000,000 bytes) **plus** ten bytes. What is going to be in the last element of the array? The question is probably going to be academic as the approach is wrong. The other programming principle of course is that optimization is the last thing that occurs after all else is settled

Comment: Two other things I don't like **a.** treating strings and files in the same method and **b.** using strings in place of enumerated types. When you do string comparisons btw, you want ```if ("FILE".equals(type))``` . Ask yourself why. Note that's not "TYPE" - you are referring to something that's been passed as a parameter, and therefore by definition is not a constant, even if might have originated in one. If, say, you were forced by a very early jvm to use strings as enumerated types, then that would be ```if (FILE.equals(type))``` because you'd be comparing a passed variable to a constant

Comment: When g00se says "lets say the *input* is ... plus 10 bytes" he means the input *file*. Suppose the file is 10485760 + 10 = 10485770 bytes. Now your `buffer` is created as `byte[] buffer = new byte[10485760];` so your going to make two trips through the subsequent loop, in the first you might fill up the `buffer` reading 10485760 bytes and adding it to `temp` and in the second you'll read 10 bytes but you'll still have whatever was left over in the remain 10485750 bytes; that's the *garbage*. But it's even worse then that because what you're adding to `temp` is the reference to `buffer`, so ..

Comment: ... and you add *the same reference every time*, so if what you are get are multiple copies of whatever was in `buffer` after the last iteration of the loop. This is true of the other paths through your code as well. In addition, you should use SHA256 which is both faster and much more secure than MD2.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have changed the code, please check, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Finally, you cannot guarantee the order that the individual threads will finish and add their hashes to `temp`, so your hash output ends up being non-deterministic.

Comment: @g00se I have tried DigestInputsream, this way it takes 440sec (~7.3 min) to complete. May I kindly ask, how to get rid of the garbage bytes left in the byte[]? Should I choose smaller byte[]? For example, 1KiB?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you for the help, do you have an idea how to handle the garbage, I relatively new to this. About the invokeAll, it is executing the threads in the correct order and returns the futures accordingly, "in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: ok, you are correct about invokeAll. But the other egregious bug remains. The whole approach is suspect. Taking a hash of hashes of chunks is a different function than taking a hash of the entire contents. If would be very surprising if the hash of hashes ended up being weaker than the single hash of everything, but it's still a different function, one that the hash function designers did not have in mind and one that has received none of the analysis that the real hash function received.

Comment: Just -STOP. Don't describe the code you think you need or the steps. Describe the [GOAL](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/117-smart-questions). Yes, we know it's "hashing a large" file, but what's with the string and the chunks? Seriously ```DigestInputStream```  is your friend and don't even think about multi-threading until you've got the core problem sorted out. If Occam's Razor has a reverse mode, you're currently in it

Comment: I can see @Thend, that you can take direction and apply improvements, and all that's great. But don't think you can tweak your way out of this. You can't, as the fundamental approach is wrong. Please start by describing in simple words what your goal is, then we can help you

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk my approach is not to make the hash stronger or anything like that, is is just to hash piece by piece and to generate a final single hash for the input. There is an approach I'm using called Hash list (or Hash tree): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_list ,also successive hashing is a known approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain). I'm sorry If I cannot clearly explain my approach, I try to explain it in the following comment addressed to g00se

Comment: @g00se The situation is the following, I have a simple program which can generate hashes for text, files and directories. The core of this program (as I call) is two methods. One method creates the input (I call it parser), the other method (I call it encrypt) generates the hash. I have to stick to this, since the program currently can use 34 different hash algorithm, so I cannot change this core part. The key problem is that I'm facing that hash generation is extremely slow in case of MD2 (I have noticed it is much faster for other algorithms). To this reason, I tried to parallelize. :)

Comment: OK but that's not *quite* the goal is it? The fact that you use the word 'encrypt' incorrectly doesn't bode well. Why do you want hashes, iow what is the *goal*?

Comment: @g00se This program can be used for identifying file duplicates, corrupted files, verify the integrity of a files...etc. For example, in a court hearing, it can be proven whether a document has been forged or not. There ore tonnes of use in computer(data) security. Another example is whether a photo altered or not, or some document is fake or not.

Comment: OK, then the way to accomplish it is to use a DigestInputStream on files. Strings are a separate issue and are not normally subject to this kind of treatment. I'm not sure why you'd have them at all...

Comment: @g00se okay, I agree :) may I kindly ask, is it possible to parallelize somehow with DigestInputStream, or how can I speed it up even more? This speed is shockingly slow for example if I want to hash a complete disk. Please, suggest if possible :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248178/discussion-between-g00se-and-thend).